# Is it easy to evade a ban if you have a Dynamic IP?

Tags: ip, internet

Static IP, I get it. Once it gets banned, you are done on that IP.

But what about Dynamic ones? Let's say I am playing on a game server and the administrators decide to ban me for cheating. They ban the IP I was using that specific time, correct?

But Dynamic IPs change pretty often so does that mean I will be able to normally log-in again once it changes? Is it that simple as it sounds?

1. Does someone have to restart the router in order for their IP to change or can it happen randomly while browsing on the Internet etc? (assuming it's a Dynamic IP)
2. When an IP changes, does the ISP change it completely or only the last few digits? For example from 94.544.453.erty (didn't want to finish it with numbers) to 94.544.453.sfrf. Or is it possible to also go from 94.544* to like 94.434*?
3. Do internet cafes have Dynamic or Static IPs usually? The reason I am asking is; if a cafe user gets banned from a server for cheating then does that mean whole cafe (30+ players) is pretty much unable to play on that server?
4. Is it true that you can't find someone's location accurately if they having a Dynamic IP? For example, it might say that you live 10kms away from your actual location.
5. If it's so easy to evade a ban by using a VPN or even by having a Dynamic IP then why do they keep issuing IP bans? Is this the only way to prevent someone from having access to something?

Comment: Most of this is not really about information security (how ISP changes IP, how to trigger a change, what the new IP will look like, will hotspots use dynamic IP). Others is about bypassing security measures (banning) which is off-topic. Apart from that it is too broad - how a ban is done depends on the game and with many one will probably just ban a specific account which is independent from the IP address.

Comment: I see. Where should I ask to get detailed answers regarding my questions? Thanks.

Comment: It might not be that easy: some parts you might ask at superuser.com, some you find out yourself when finding more out how ISP connectivity works, for some you might ask a more specific question ... As for the ISP: they have various IP network blocks and can only give you an IP from such blocks, i.e. very similar IP's. And with DSL or Cable the IP is provided when your router connects and authenticates to the ISP. And since the same IP blocks are shared with many users one cannot derive the exact location from IP.  And internet cafes usually have the same fixed external IP for their users.

Comment: ISPs can handle IPs very differently from one another, including what triggers a change. The same thing for game servers. How they ban is *completely* up to them. Ask your ISP the ISP questions, test your game server on a banned IP to see the limits of their banning process.

Comment: You said something about network blocks and there is something I noticed. I checked my IP the past 9 months or so and sometimes I was getting a different IP after a month or so. I didn't change ISP, location etc. What triggered that? Or does ISP just decide to change it? Also the IPs differed, one was starting with 94* for example, the new one with 123*. I thought only the last digits change. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general a "block" will beaten with a new IP if it's an IP block. I'd suggest VPN as you can't control your ISP and their are different ways that they do IP reservations and NAT. It is possible to block on useragent and some other things also, but in general I see IP bans used the most. IP bans are a flawed way to stop an attacker. When we ban IP's we run the risk of shutting down connectivity for multiple users who share that IP. Why is this still used? There isn't much else when you have a really malicious attacker. Good SOC's and IR are aware of these issues and usually bans have a shelf life: 30 days being one I'm familiar with personally.

Turning your router off and on might, but probably won't change your IP. You will most likely have a "lease" and that will change depending upon it's time limit. Internet cafe's will have IP's based on their ISP and plan, most of which seem to be a standard enterprise plan without anything fancy like a reserved IP range or etc. On the note of if the new IP will be close to the last one, yes most likely. IP's cost money to "own" so typically buy a sequential range so you'll get assigned randomly to another in the range, very close to the last one.

I'd suggest asking the geolocation question separately from this post as it is a very different topic.

Comment: Evading bans based solely on changing your IP address isn't as easy as it was a few years ago.  Many implementations now include other fingerprints (like the useragent you mentioned).